# How to remove white stripes in TIN generated in Arcgis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, tin, smoothing

[image]
I've generated TIN from DEM data using toolbox (3Danalyst/conversion/from raster/raster to tin) in arc-desktop 10.2. I'm getting these stripes, I tried altering toolbox parameter values but couldn't solve it, could anybody help?

Comment: Looks like you have noise/artifacts in the input data. Does the hillshade raster/contours generated from the same source data exhibit similar anomalies?